# React useCallback in useEffect cleanup

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a websocket manager using a react hook that other components can leverage for managing websocket sessions with a simple library like:

```
export const useWebsocketSession = (onMessage: (data: string) => void) => {
   const [session, setSession] = useState<WebSocket | undefined>();

   const connect = useCallback(() => {
      const ws = new WebSocket(baseURL);

      // Not relevant for this post
      ws.onopen = () => {...}
      ws.onclose = () => {...}
      ws.onerror = () => {...}
      ws.onmessage = (ev: MessageEvent<string>) => onMessage(ev.data);

      setSession(ws);
   }, []);

   const close = useCallback(() => {
      if (!session) {
         console.log("no session!");
         return;
      }

      if (session.readyState === session.OPEN) {
         console.log("closing as normal");
         session.close(1000);
      }
      setSession(null);
   }, [session]);

   return { connect, close };
}
```

Then, in a component that wants to use sockets, I use the hook as follows:

```
export const WebsocketUser = () => {
   const onMessage = (data: string) => {
      ...
   }

   const { open, close } = useWebsocketSession(onMessage);

   useEffect(() => {
      open();
      
      return () => { 
         console.log("attempting to close");
         close();
      }
   }, []);
}
```

What I notice is that on rendering of the `WebsocketUser` component, the socket session successfully opens, is able to authenticate, and handle messages as expected. However, then when the component is destroyed, the `useEffect` cleanup will run, but the version of the `close` function that it runs still points to an empty session, even though the session has been created and is clearly handling messages. I'm guessing that when the useEffect is initialized, it caches a local version of the `close` function that has a null session reference, which is never updated even as the `close` callback changes as a result of the `session` dependency being updated.

Can someone point me to details about this behavior? What is the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the previous instance of `close`, since you haven't set `close` as the dependency of `useEffect`, and when you set the `session` set, `close` is recreated. So the standard (**mistaken**) answer would be to declare the dependencies:

```
useEffect(() => {
  connect();

  return () => {
    console.log("attempting to close");
    close();
  }
}, [connect, close]);
```

However, this would cause an infinite loop, since `close` would be called with the previous `session` (changing the `session` to `null`), and `open` would be called again, creating a new `session`, re-creating `close`, which would trigger the `useEffect` again, and cause an infinite loop.

**Option 1** - you don't need a `state`, and the `connect` function should return the `close` function:

```
export const useWebsocketSession = (onMessage: (data: string) => void) => 
  useCallback(() => {
    const ws = new WebSocket(baseURL);

    // Not relevant for this post
    ws.onopen = () => {...}
    ws.onclose = () => {...}
    ws.onerror = () => {...}
    ws.onmessage = (ev: MessageEvent<string>) => onMessage(ev.data);

    return close = () => {
      if (session.readyState === session.OPEN) {
        console.log("closing as normal");
        session.close(1000);
      }
    }
  }, [onMessage]); // onMessage is a dependency
```

Now you can use it in the consumer:

```
const connect = useWebsocketSession(onMessage);

useEffect(() => {
  return connect(); // connects and returns `close` for cleanup
}, [connect]);
```

**Option 2** - use a ref instead of the state:

```
export const useWebsocketSession = (onMessage: (data: string) => void) => {
  const session = useRef<WebSocket | null>(null);

  const connect = useCallback(() => {
    const ws = new WebSocket(baseURL);

    // Not relevant for this post
    ws.onopen = () => {...}
    ws.onclose = () => {...}
    ws.onerror = () => {...}
    ws.onmessage = (ev: MessageEvent<string>) => onMessage(ev.data);

    session.current = ws; // save the session on the ref
  }, [onMessage]);

  const close = useCallback(() => {
    if (!session.current) {
      console.log("no session!");
      return;
    }

    if (session.current.readyState === session.OPEN) {
      console.log("closing as normal");
      session.current.close(1000);
    }
    
    session.current = null;
  }, []); // no need for dependencies

  return {
    connect,
    close
  };
}
```

And this would work with this `useEffect`:

```
const { connect, close } = useWebsocketSession(onMessage);

useEffect(() => {
  connect();

  return () => {
    console.log("attempting to close");
    close();
  }
}, [connect, close]); // set the dependencies
```

**Note**: in both options don't forget to memoize `onMessage` with `useCallback` as well. If you won't memoize it, on render `connect` might be recreated again and again, and you'll get an infinite loop.